# spring security core for Grails not compiling

Tags: grails, spring-security

The spring security core plugin for Grails is not compiling/installing. The download is successful but it's not compiling. The errors are as follows: ...

```
|Installed plugin spring-security-core-2.0-RC2
.....................
|Compiling 185 source files  
[groovyc] org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
[groovyc] Compile error during compilation with javac.
[groovyc] F:\apa repo\apa  server\target\work\plugins\spring-security-core-2.0-RC2\src\java\grails\plugin\springsecurity\CryptoEncoderWrapper.java:28: error: package org.springframework.security.crypto.password does not exist
[groovyc]   protected final org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder delegate;
[groovyc]                                                               ^
[groovyc] F:\apa repo\apa  server\target\work\plugins\spring-security-core-2.0-RC2\src\java\grails\plugin\springsecurity\CryptoEncoderWrapper.java:33: error: package org.springframework.security.crypto.password does not exist
[groovyc]   public CryptoEncoderWrapper(org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder encoder) {
[groovyc]                                                                           ^
[groovyc] F:\apa repo\apa  server\target\work\plugins\spring-security-core-2.0-RC2\src\java\grails\plugin\springsecurity\SpringSecurityUtils.java:46: error: cannot find symbol
[groovyc] import org.springframework.security.core.authority.SimpleGrantedAuthority;
[groovyc]                                                   ^
[groovyc]   symbol:   class SimpleGrantedAuthority
[groovyc]   location: package org.springframework.security.core.authority
[groovyc] F:\apa repo\apa  server\target\work\plugins\spring-security-core-2.0-RC2\src\java\grails\plugin\springsecurity\SpringSecurityUtils.java:58: error: cannot find symbol
[groovyc] import org.springframework.security.web.util.AnyRequestMatcher;
[groovyc]                                             ^
[groovyc]   symbol:   class AnyRequestMatcher
[groovyc]   location: package org.springframework.security.web.util
[groovyc] F:\apa repo\apa  server\target\work\plugins\spring-security-core-2.0-RC2\src\java\grails\plugin\springsecurity\access\vote\ClosureVoter.java:35: error: type AccessDecisionVoter does not take parameters
[groovyc] public class ClosureVoter implements AccessDecisionVoter<FilterInvocation>, ApplicationContextAware {
[groovyc]                                                         ^
[groovyc] F:\apa repo\apa  server\target\work\plugins\spring-security-core-2.0-RC2\src\java\grails\plugin\springsecurity\authentication\GrailsAnonymousAuthenticationToken.java:23: error: cannot find symbol
```

... And many more similar to these

Comment: are you mixing different plugin versions or force some spring-security versions along in the deps?  have you tried removing your target dir and do a `grails package` after that?  is your grails version reasonable new?

Comment: @cfrick No the problem is coming even with a single version of Spring Security. I am not forcing any versions in dependencies - in fact I don't know how to do it. After your suggestion I removed target dir & did a 'package'. The same errors come while compiling these files. My Grails version is 2.4.3 & is perfectly compatible with the said demands of the Spring Security Core - on it's plugin page. Many Thanks.

Comment: @cfrick Is it true that sometimes you get into a lot of issues with GGTS/Grails, that stall your work. It's a matter of luck. I have also had too many days when no problems came by, & now it's like hell:-). I am not even able to debug with GGTS.

Comment: you are bashing GGTS as if the problem is only there.  does it work with plain grails on commandline?  also RC2 is not the newest version of the plugin and also 2.4.3 is not the newest grails version on 2.4.  your problem could be already fixed. RC4 and 2.4.4 are a sane bundle.

Comment: @cfrick the problem is coming on RC4 also. I will check the other things & tell.

Comment: @cfrick It doesn't run with Grails on the command line. The same problem is coming. The problem is also coming on Grails 2.4.4 & Spring Security RC4.

Comment: I'm having compilation problems in Grails 2.4.4 with spring security 2.0 RC5, any ideas?